# Grid column with width="*" does not use all available space as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid, wpf-listview

I have a problem with my first ListView usage. My custom item should have (currently) 2 rows with 3 columns each containing a label (1st column width="Auto"), a textbox (fill-up 2nd column  (tested with="*" or width="100*") and a button in the 3rd column (width="Auto")

Unfortunately the second column does not scale to use full Listview width but behaves like width="Auto".

Note that initially I used a StackPanel as top control in the DataTemplate and replaced it by a grid, just to check if it could solve the problem.

Testing the DataTemplate Grid in a test application directely in a window dows work as expected.

```
              <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Input Paths"/>
                <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PathListAccess.PathList.PathList}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <!--Row 0-->
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Input Directory:"/>
                                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding InputPath}"/>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="..."/>
                                    <!--Row 1-->
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Output Directory:"/>
                                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding OutputPath}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: Unless you set the ListView's View property, better use the simpler ListBox base class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You are of course right. Views are not yet set because they are in the pipeline for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `ListView` default value for `HorizontalContentAlignment` is `Left`.

Try to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PathListAccess.PathList.PathList}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Great help! I would have searched for a long to find this as I was looking for the problem up to the ItemTemplate level only..  Than You!